# jQuery Replace Link Text with Show and Hide

Tags: jquery, toggle, show-hide

I'm trying to change some 'Show More' link text to 'Show Less' once the associated content has been revealed, using jQuery.

I have [created a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/016h69a9/) to illustrate what I have done so far. I also need the content to close when I then click on the 'Show Less' link.

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('.reveal_more').click(function(){
        jQuery('.box').hide();
        jQuery('#item-'+jQuery(this).attr('target')).show();
    });
});
```

I wondered if someone might be able to help me out? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.text(function)`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function) to set text of your anchor element and based on its text value you can show/hide target using [`.toggle( boolean)`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display)

*Code*

```
jQuery('.reveal_more').click(function(){
    jQuery('.box').hide();

    //Switch text              
    $(this).text(function(_, val){
        return val == "Show More" ? "Show Less" : "Show More"
    });

    //Toogle target element        
    jQuery('#item-'+jQuery(this).attr('target')).toggle($(this).text() == "Show Less");

});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/L8xzLj3z/)

Comment: Thanks Satpal. Is it possible that if you click on a few of the 'Show More' links, the text of the closed items could go back to 'Show More' instead of retaining the 'Show Less'?